# SQL: Compare difference in two columns of different rows and compare with value

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

So, I have the following table.

- DT - date,
- NUM_A - number,
- DUR - duration in seconds.

  Table is ordered by DT.
  When two close rows (27 and 28 rows) have same DUR values (33) then compare with  **DT(27th row) - DT(28th row)**  value. 
  If DUR > DT27-DT28 THEN I want 27th row (earliest record) to be in select result.

Comment: Tag dbms used, the answer may be product specific. (Many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: I rather need a concept/algorithm so solution can be provided in ansi SQL.

Comment: I presume this is about Oracle because of the PL/SQL tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, I am developing in pl/sql. But, this problem is just small part of bigger. So, I am expecting possible solutions in "pure" SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(dur) over (order by dt) as next_dur,
             lead(dt) over (order by dt) as next_dt
      from t
     ) t
where next_dur = dur and
      dur / (24*60*60) > (next_dt - dt);
```

Your question doesn't mention the `NUM_A` column, but you might want `partition by NUM_A` in the analytic functions.